# win+e to open new tab in windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> windows opens a new Explorer.

I would like if I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, and Explorer is already running, it opens a new tab in the Explorer already running, rather than opening a new Explorer.

Is that possible?

I know that if Explorer has focus, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, but my situation is when Explorer does NOT have focus.

Comment: So I presume this is about Windows 11…?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows 11

Comment: @PeterPoulsen - Windows 11 22H2 I presume?  What build exactly? There are multiple versions of 22H2 running around, with A/B feature testing enabled, so that information is important.

Comment: Edition: Windows 11 Pro. Version: 22H2. Os build: 22621.819

Answer (score 2):

I've created a utility that forces open tabs instead of a new window:
[Explorer Tab Utility](https://github.com/w4po/ExplorerTabUtility)

It intercepts Win+E keys and File Explorer's directory opening to open a new tab instead.

[image: Win+E Tabs]

[image: ShowInFolder]

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in option to enable this at the moment, but you can use the [WinENFET](https://github.com/tariibaba/winENFET) to do it. After you run the app, pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will open a new tab in the existing File Explorer window.